# On an arm64 PC with amd64 translation; can I install an application with apt twice, targeting both architectures but called with different commands?

Tags: debian, apt, arm

apt seems to prevent allowing the installation of two versions of a package at the same time:

```bash
$ sudo apt install make:amd64
$ sudo apt install make:arm64
```

My system is natively arm64 but I have amd64 translation and need amd64 libraries to add support for certain amd64 binaries which depend on those libraries.

That said, I was curious to try comparing the performance of amd64 translated and native arm64 applications.

Can I install two applications side by side with apt applying an alias to one?

```bash
$ sudo apt install tar:amd64 --alias tar_amd64
$ sudo apt install tar:arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t install packages containing programs for two different architectures in parallel because they ship conflicting files; in `tar`’s case, at least `/bin/tar` and `/usr/sbin/rmt-tar`.

However you can manually extract the relevant binaries to compare their performance:

```
apt download tar:amd64
dpkg-deb -x tar_*_amd64.deb tar-amd64
```

This will leave `tar-amd64/bin/tar`, which you should be able to run and compare with your `arm64` `/bin/tar`.

Most libraries are installed in architecture-specific directories (such as `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and `/usr/lib/arm64-linux-gnu`), and if their package metadata allows it, `apt` will let you install them in parallel.